# Why does simple Jenkins workflow wait indefinitely for executor?

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I am trying to dive into the world of Jenkins workflows, but am already stuck when using a node for 'hello world'.

Using this workflow:

```
node {
    echo "hello world"
}
```

the console shows this:

```
Started by user anonymous
[Workflow] Allocate node : Start
Still waiting to schedule task
Waiting for next available executor
```

I have plenty of executors available (incl. master); other (non-workflow) jobs run just fine. It's on latest LTS (1.625.3) and latest workflow (1.11). "anonymous" had admin rights on this instance.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the build-blocker plugin is interfering. After updating build-blocker to 1.7.2, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, fixed in build-blocker 1.7.2
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29295